# html: вопрос про отображение большого кол-ва объектов

Tags: html, jquery, загрузка, lazyloading

Вопрос больше концептуальный, но и про технику тоже будет :)

У меня на сайте отображается очень большое кол-во «карточек» — изображений и информации под ними (1000+ штук).

Сортировки, фильтрации, поиск — всё есть.

Вопрос в том, как лучше в 21 веке формировать эту информацию:

1) разбить на страницы, на каждой из которых будет подгружаться небольшое кол-во «карточек»;

2) «подгружать постепенно «карточки», при мотании скроллинга в браузере.

Думаю, что п.2) лучше всего подойдёт для такой задачи. Что скажете?

Вопрос — в этом случае как лучше реализовывать? Отслеживать перемещение скроллинга до упора и после этого создавать новые элементы в конце страницы? Но хотелось бы немного работать на опережение, чтобы пользователь не замечал явно подгрузки.

---

**UPD** на основе ответов:

> Во-вторых, вам придется как-то решать очень крупную проблему: как при
>   смене сортировки или фильтров пересортировать уже показанные карточки
>   при подгрузке новых, которые должны после показа попасть куда-нибудь в
>   середину уже имеющихся.

Тут думал просто удалять объекты в DOM и создавать новые — на нескольких сотнях карточках это происходит мгновенно (не заметно для глаза), так что тут проблема может возникнуть, только когда карточек будут тысячи и тогда надо смотреть в сторону оптимизации (удалять только то, что нужно, создавать только то, что нужно)

> В-третьих, вам либо придется удалять часть уже показанных карточек при
>   прокрутке вниз, либо мириться с прогрессивно возрастающими тормозами
>   из-за того, что карточки будут накапливаться.

Вот тут конечно вопрос надо изучить — насколько будет падение в скорости. Наверное это даже больше вопрос к браузерам — умение не тратить ресурсы на неотображаемые элементы.

> В-четвертых, вы лишаете себя возможности задать пермалинк на нужную
>   страницу (нужные N карточек).

Во-первых, при сортировке или фильтрации порядок будет разный, поэтому в пермалинке придётся указывать и эти параметры, а учитывая, что список карточек со временем будет пополняться, то даже такой пермалинк будет неэффективен

Во-вторых, ссылку на нужную карточку можно задавать через ее уникальный ID, типа такого:

```
site.php?articles=1,5,7,11
```

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос - в этом случае как лучше реализовывать? Отслеживать перемещение скроллинга до упора и после этого создавать новые элементы в конце страницы? Но хотелось бы немного работать на опережение, чтобы пользователь не замечал явно подгрузки.

Можно отслеживать размеры скроллируемой области (фактически - положение последней карточки) и делать подгрузку карточек когда юзер проскроллит, например, на 90%. Или когда, скажем, третья  с конца карточка попадает в отображаемую область.

**НО:**

Подгрузка карточек по мере скроллинга - зло, мракобесие и ересь, которую надо изжить как не имеющую нормальных реализаций и жутко непроизводительную. Это во-первых.

Во-вторых, вам придется как-то решать очень крупную проблему: как при смене сортировки или фильтров пересортировать уже показанные карточки при подгрузке новых, которые должны после показа попасть куда-нибудь в середину уже имеющихся.

В-третьих, вам либо придется удалять часть уже показанных карточек при прокрутке вниз, либо мириться с прогрессивно возрастающими тормозами из-за того, что карточки будут накапливаться.

В-четвертых, вы лишаете себя возможности задать пермалинк на нужную страницу (нужные N карточек). А пользователя, соответственно, лишаете этой возможностью пользоваться.  Необоснованное очень уважительными причинами лишение пользователя пермалинков карается в аду варкой в котле с фекалиями.

Подгрузка по мере скроллинга годится только для одной ситуации: когда а) к уже просмотренному возвращаться не требуется, б) сортировка - одна, заданная на сервере и в) пермалинки на "проскроленное вот до этого места" не нужны. То есть, для чтения всякой хрени вконтактике.

Comment: У Zhihar возникли дополнительные вопросы к вашему ответу; см. UPD в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

> Тут думал просто удалять объекты в DOM и создавать новые - на нескольких сотнях карточках это происходит мгновенно (не заметно для глаза)

Нужно думать и о тех пользователях, которые будут видеть ваши карточки не с мощных многоядерных игровых компов, а с тонких клиентов, нетбуков и планшетов и большинства смартфонов. Вот там они наплачутся, любуясь лагами и спиннером.

> Во-первых, при сортировке или фильтрации порядок будет разный, поэтому в пермалинке придётся указывать и эти параметры, а учитывая, что список карточек со временем будет пополняться, то даже такой пермалинк будет неэффективен

Не суть важно. Тут принцип как при чтении большой темы на форуме - человек может, например, пролистать десяток страниц, сделать закладку (или даже просто закрыть браузер), уйти по делам, через час вернуться и продолжить с того же места, открыв закладку или восстановив сессию браузера. Или даже просто случайно уйти со страницы и, спохватившись, вернуться назад. Пейджер спасет ему время и нервы. Сплошной поток карточек с подгрузкой этой возможности не даст.